# Spring Batch Job Parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am unable to understand this behaviour with parameter.

1) I ran the job passing customerFile parameter. currentDate is an auto-incremented parameter. The job ran successfully.

```
[{currentDate=1591470035541, customerFile=D:\Data\Study\spring-batch\file1.txt}]
```

2) when am running the job for the second time **without** passing "customerFile" parameter. It is still taking the previous value "D:\Data\Study\spring-batch\file1.txt" and running successfully.

```
    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("person-job")
                .start(step())
                .validator(batchJobParamValidator)
                .incrementer(jobParametersIncrementer)
                .build();
    }


    @StepScope
    @Bean("personFileReader")
  public FlatFileItemReader<Person> personFileReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['customerFile']}") FileSystemResource fileName) {


        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>().name("personItemReader").resource(fileName).fixedLength()
                .columns(getRange()).names(getNames()).targetType(Person.class).build();

    }
```

Comment: Can you share the commands you are using to run the job the first time and the second time as well as the logs showing the job status? Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: yes, I am using spring boot and running it in Intellij as a spring boot app passing the program adgument